# how to call an integer which is changing every time loop runs? see image linked below

Tags: c#

[how to call an integer as it is changing when loop is running i want print and calculate every single time loop runs hope you understand my question

[image]

Comment: Put your code as text in the body of your question **do not post pictures of your code**

Comment: please include the necessary contents of he link in the answer, if later on the link breaks, your answer will be useless

Comment: I think you should explain a little bit more

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This site requires code, not links to pictures of code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the line

```
total = perunit * quanitity
```

to

```
total += perunit * quantity
```

this will add the result to total, not override total every time.